# How to remove duplicates while importing a CSV with Apex?

Tags: apex

I have this code that imports a CSV into a custom objects and works fine, but I want to remove duplicates during the import. I added the list to a map but there are still duplicates. I assume this happens because PJ is being added to the map but I don't know how to implement this without it. I have 2 identical records in my file and both records are importing. Can you please help?

```
public class sample_Cntlr {

public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<Project__c> prjLst{get;set;}
Map<String,Project__c> prjMap = new Map<String,Project__c>(); 

  public sample_Cntlr(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    prjLst = New List<Project__c>(); 
  }  
  public void importCSVFile(){
       try{
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 

           for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
               Project__c prjObj = new Project__c();
               string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');

               prjObj.Year__c = csvRecordData[0];             
               prjObj.Payable_To__c = csvRecordData[1];

               prjLst.add(prjObj);                                                                 
           }

           for(Project__c pj : prjLst){
              prjMap.put(prjLst[0].Year__c,pj);     
           }
           if(prjMap.size()>0){
             insert prjMap.values();
           }               

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct' + '- System: ' + e);
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the criteria for identifying duplicates, viz., which fields participate in that?

Comment: Hi Jayant, right now in my example I'm just using the year. I tried using an external id and it didn't work either. The duplicates got imported without the external ID.

Comment: So as long as you have the `Year` as the `Key` in your map, any repeating `Year` will override the earlier one in the map. That would mean, there's always one record for a particular Year. Your issue seems that you are always adding the same year thus leading to only one record -- `prjLst[0].Year__c`. Instead you will need to use `prjMap.put(pj.Year__c,pj)`

Comment: I tried that and sadly the duplicates are still there.

Comment: Did you mean for 'Unique ID' field?  because you can have multiple records with the same External ID, though this it is not recommended.

Comment: @Snights As long as you have same year as key, there won't be a scenario where you will have two different entries in the map. Keys are always unique in map. Any old value associated with that year will get overridden. I am not sure if I follow when you say duplicates are still there.

Comment: @JayantDas when I import 2 identical records using the map above both records will be imported as opposed to just one. I believe adding pj to the map could be adding its id thus making them unique. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @MenashYA using a unique field just fails the entire import since there are duplicates. I'm trying to remove the duplicates during the import process.

Comment: @Snights Adding `pj` to the map is just adding it as value against a key which in your case is a year value. So if you have say `<2019, PJ1>` and `<2019, PJ2>` .. and that you are adding it in iteration, the only value that you will get added to the map against 2019 will be `PJ2`. I am not sure how you map ends up with two distinct `pj` objects against 2019, that shouldn't ever happen.

Comment: One of the strings is probably padded with a whitespace character. This CSV parsing code (I know everyone uses it!) is not very resilient against the vagaries of the format.